# Embedding a Plotly chart in a Django template

Tags: python, django, plotly

I am trying to embed a plotly pie chart in a Django html template. This works fine when the chart is produced in 'online mode' (i.e. the html snippet is stored on the plotly server) but not in 'offline mode' (i.e. when the html is stored locally). In the latter case, the chart does not appear. I want to be able to store the html on my local server and embed the plots from there.

Here is the bit that works:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
labels = [1,2,3,4]
values = [10,20,30,40]
ndata = 100
fig = {
    'data': [{'labels': labels,
          'values': values,
          'type': 'pie',
          'textposition':"none",
          'textinfo':"percent",
          'textfont':{'size':'12'},
          'showlegend':'false'}],
    'layout': {'title': 'Total:'+str(ndata),
           'showlegend':'false',
           'height':'200',
           'width':'200',
           'autosize':'false',
           'margin':{'t':'50','l':'75','r':'0','b':'10'},
           'separators':'.,'}
}
plotly_url = py.plot(fig, filename='myfile', auto_open=False)
pie_url = '<iframe width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" src='+plotly_url+'.embed?width=200&height=200&link=false&showlegend=false></iframe>'
```

Note that **pie_url** is passed as a string in the Http render request in Django. The template interprets the string as html using the **|** safe tag, i.e. {{ pie_url|safe }}.

Here is the bit that doesn't work:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
labels = [1,2,3,4]
values = [10,20,30,40]
ndata = 100
fig = {
    'data': [{'labels': labels,
          'values': values,
          'type': 'pie',
          'textposition':"none",
          'textinfo':"percent",
          'textfont':{'size':'12'},
          'showlegend':'false'}],
    'layout': {'title': 'Total:'+str(ndata),
           'showlegend':'false',
           'height':'200',
           'width':'200',
           'autosize':'false',
           'margin':{'t':'50','l':'75','r':'0','b':'10'},
           'separators':'.,'}
}
plotly_url = plot(fig, filename='file:///home/website/pie.html', auto_open=False)
pie_url = '''<iframe width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" src=\"'''+plotly_url+'''.embed?width=200&height=200&link=false&showlegend=false\"></iframe>'''
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to output it to a .html file?

Comment: Hi, Yes, the html file gets produced. But it does not show up when Django renders it (this is the pie_url line in the original post.)

Comment: Is it correct that the string saved into pie_url is wrapped between triple ' instead of just single ' ?

Answer (score 56):

Instead of writing the html to a file you can have plotly return the html part of the graph as a string. For example, using a class based TemplateView:

**EDIT: Update for using recent (as of 2021/08) versions of plotly. The template does not need any changes.**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

class Graph(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'graph.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Graph, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        x = [-2,0,4,6,7]
        y = [q**2-q+3 for q in x]
        trace1 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104, 'size': "10"},
                            mode="lines",  name='1st Trace')

        layout=go.Layout(title="Meine Daten", xaxis={'title':'x1'}, yaxis={'title':'x2'})
        figure=go.Figure(data=['trace1'],layout=layout)

        context['graph'] = figure.to_html()

        return context
```

This is the original code:

```
import plotly.offline as opy
import plotly.graph_objs as go

class Graph(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'graph.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Graph, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        x = [-2,0,4,6,7]
        y = [q**2-q+3 for q in x]
        trace1 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104, 'size': "10"},
                            mode="lines",  name='1st Trace')

        data=go.Data([trace1])
        layout=go.Layout(title="Meine Daten", xaxis={'title':'x1'}, yaxis={'title':'x2'})
        figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
        div = opy.plot(figure, auto_open=False, output_type='div')

        context['graph'] = div

        return context
```

and the template:

```
{% if graph %}
<div style="width:600;height:500">
{{ graph|safe }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can probably put this in your views to render this context     
    `g = Graph()` 
    `context = g.get_context_data()`
    `return render(request, 'app/stats.html', context)`

EDIT: use TemplateViews directly in urls https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview

Comment: For all those not familiar with class-based views, to make the code working, remember to add from django.views.generic import TemplateView. Also, read the docs pointed out by Naman

Comment: Thanks! This is so much easier than using matplotlib.

Answer (score 34):

There's been a couple of updates to plotly, some of which are applicable here for **plotly 4+**:

- [Plotly is offline by default now](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/)

  > Note: **No internet connection, account, or payment is required to use plotly.py.** Prior to version 4, this library could operate in either an "online" or "offline" mode. The documentation tended to emphasize the online mode, where graphs get published to the Chart Studio web service. In version 4, all "online" functionality was removed from the plotly package and is now available as the separate, optional, chart-studio package (See below). **plotly.py version 4 is "offline" only, and does not include any functionality for uploading figures or data to cloud services.**
- Figures now have a [`to_html`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.to_html.html?highlight=to_html) function

This allows you to do the following to embed a graph **offline**:

```
graph = fig.to_html(full_html=False, default_height=500, default_width=700)
context = {'graph': graph}
response = render(request, 'graph.html', context)
```

And in `graph.html` you can do:

```html
{% if graph %}
{{ graph|safe }}
{% else %}
<p>No graph was provided.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose that your piece of code that draws the graph, i.e.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
labels = [1,2,3,4]
values = [10,20,30,40]
ndata = 100
fig = {
    'data': [{'labels': labels,
          'values': values,
          'type': 'pie',
          'textposition':"none",
          'textinfo':"percent",
          'textfont':{'size':'12'},
          'showlegend':'false'}],
    'layout': {'title': 'Total:'+str(ndata),
           'showlegend':'false',
           'height':'200',
           'width':'200',
           'autosize':'false',
           'margin':{'t':'50','l':'75','r':'0','b':'10'},
           'separators':'.,'}
}
plotly_url = plot(fig, filename='file:///home/website/pie.html', auto_open=False)
pie_url = '''<iframe width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" src=\"'''+plotly_url+'''.embed?width=200&height=200&link=false&showlegend=false\"></iframe>'''
```

is a funtion named `graph_function()`. Inside that one, just substitute

```
plotly_url = plot(fig, filename='file:///home/website/pie.html', auto_open=False)
pie_url = '''<iframe width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" src=\"'''+plotly_url+'''.embed?width=200&height=200&link=false&showlegend=false\"></iframe>'''
```

with

```
plt_div = plotly.offline.plot(fig, output_type='div')

return plt_div
```

then in your views.py:

```
def graph_view(request):
    my_graph=graph_function()
    context={'graph':my_graph}
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context_dict)
```

and then in your template:

```
{% if graph %}
{{ graph|safe }}
{% else %}
<p>No graph was provided.</p>
{% endif %}
```