# ipython plotly map render on a django template

Tags: python, django, plotly

This is what I am doing in an ipython notebook where the plotly graphs and everything gets generated without fail. After that I am taking the html form of the notebook and embedding it in a django template where everything is working other than the plotly graphs. I am not sure what needs to be done thats why I also tried installing plotly on npm and also including a reference to plotly.js through my template. Below are the codes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

data = pd.read_csv("storage/AviationDataUp.csv")

useful_columns = ['Event.Date', 'Location', 'Country', 'Latitude', 'Longitude',     'Purpose.of.Flight',\
              'Total.Fatal.Injuries','Number.of.Engines','Air.Carrier']
data = data[useful_columns]
data = data[data['Country']=='United States']

accident_trace = Scattergeo(
    locationmode = 'ISO-3',
    lon = data['Longitude'],
    lat = data['Latitude'],
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict( 
        size = 2,
        opacity = 0.75,
        color="rgb(0, 130, 250)"),
    name = 'Accidents'
)

layout = dict(
    title = 'Aviation Accidents in USA',
    geo = dict(
        scope = 'usa',
        projection = dict(),
        showland = True,
        landcolor = 'rgb(250, 250, 250)',
        subunitwidth = 1,
        subunitcolor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)',
        countrywidth = 1,
        countrycolor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)',
        showlakes = True,
        lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
    ) )


figure = dict(data=Data([accident_trace]), layout=layout)
iplot(figure)
```

Comment: here is a similar question with a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846395/embedding-a-plotly-chart-in-a-django-template