# Plotly showing characters not rendering graph

Tags: python, django, plotly

I am new to Python, Django, and Plotly. I am trying to render a graph but I am unable to do so. The images below depict my problem. When my page loads it displays the graph as a set of characters of the sort. When I click F12 it shows the second image, just partially rendering the graph. I am not sure where I went wrong, I would really appreciate your help.

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    valuesX = [];
    valuesY = [];
    results = DTH.objects.filter(date__gte = '2019-12-01', date__lte = '2019-12-31');
    for row in results:
        valuesX.append(row.date);
        valuesY.append(row.price);
    #fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=[0,1,2,3], y=[0,1,2,3])]);
    fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=valuesX, y=valuesY)]);
    plt_div = plot(fig, output_type='div', show_link=False, link_text="")
    return render_to_response('app/index.html', { 'plt_div': plt_div })
```

[image: Image One: Plotly rendered character]

[image: Image Two: When F12 is clicked it displays this]

Comment: This link may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846395/embedding-a-plotly-chart-in-a-django-template

Answer (score 1):

Try to update a layout of the graph by either setting its autosize paramether to True or providing the height and width of the graph

```
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
)
```

or

```
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=500,
)
```